# .cshrc で設定した環境変数を .xprofile に引き継ぎたい

Tags: linux, bash

普段 tcsh を使用しており、環境変数等の設定は ~/.cshrc で行っています。
lxdm を使うにあたり、環境変数の設定は ~/.xprofile で行うもののようですが、.cshrc と .xprofile と設定を二重に持ちたくはないので、.xprofile から .cshrc を読み込み、なんとかしたいと考えています。

で、作ったのが以下の .xprofile です。

```
tmp=/tmp/xprofile.$$
tcsh -c 'source ~/.cshrc; env' | sed -e 's/^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)$/export \1="\2"/' > $tmp

. $tmp

rm $tmp
```

一応動いてはいるようです。
中には値に「;」が含まれているものもありますので、「"\2"」と quote しています。
しかしそれでも、値に「"」が含まれていると誤動作すると思われ、完璧ではありません。

完璧にする方法、または全く違う方法をご存じの方、いらっしゃったら教えて下さい。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `. <(tcsh -c 'source ~/.cshrc; printenv' | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;s/^.*$/export \$'&'/")` ではどうでしょう。`$'&'` としているのは改行コードなどのエスケープシーケンスに対応するためです。また、`eval $(tcsh -c ...)` でも同じ結果になります。

Comment: key & valueの単純なペアなら共通に使えるファイルをつくっておいて、両者からそれぞれ読み込むのはどうでしょう。と書いたところで、もうすでにほぼそれをやっていますね。$tmpを正式に別ファイルとしてメンテするのでいいのでは？

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi tcsh と bash とでは環境変数の設定方法が異なりますので、$tmp そのままでは、今度は tcsh の方が大変になってきますね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

argus さんのコメントの方法が完璧でした。
.xprofile 中で `. <()` の書き方ができないようでしたので、今回は `eval $()` の方でやりました。

```
eval $(tcsh -c 'source ~/.cshrc; printenv' | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;s/^.*$/export \$'&'/")
```

回答ありがとうございました。